# Javafx pane with x and y coordinates

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, javafx, pane

Could you please tell me if there is a pane in javafx I can use to position my nodes by X and Y value. I would use a `Group` class but it isn't very functional. I want a resizable layout that fits to its parent (Stage in this case) and I must be able to apply css to it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure how the children should behave on resize, but if they should remain at the exact same offset from the top-left, use `Pane` - or any other layout with `managed` set to `false` for the children.

Comment: "resizable layout" would seem to contradict "position my nodes by X and Y".  What exactly are trying to do?

Comment: @fabian Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a `GridPane`.
You add content to it with the 'gridPane.add(node, x, y)', which places the specified node at the specified x,y coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much